# AngularJs using ng-init variable in ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, ng-init

All styles apply in result.
What's wrong with this selection?

```
 <div  ng-init="selectedItem = elements">
   <div class="nav-item" ng-class="{'someStyle' : selectedItem === elements}" 
        ng-click="selectedItem = elements" ></div>
   <div class="nav-item"  ng-class="{'someStyle' : selectedItem === inspector}" 
        ng-click="selectedItem = inspector" > </div>
   <div class="nav-item" ng-class="{'someStyle' : selectedItem === pages}" 
         ng-click="selectedItem = pages" > </div>
</div>
```

Comment: elements is a string or a variable in your scope?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will get better answers if you can ask questions well, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some tips.

Comment: All those things are `undefined` in your scope and thus are all equal to each other.